# Tooltip and Y Axis data Points mismatch SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I have a SSRS report which shows CPU Trend of Quarters in a year. Below is my chart. The chart tooltip values 12% for Q1 and 9% for Q2 which matches the data from the query. But the Axis values are so different and it represent some wrong values.

[image]
I' not sure what I missed. I have not add any customization to the Axis so by default it should align to the values of data. Please help to adjust the Y Axis accordingly,.